# Unable to write to file using Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have written following code I am able to print out the parsed values of Lat and lon but  i am unable to write them to a file. I tried flush and also i tried closing the file but of no use. Can somebody point out whats wrong here.

```
import os
import serial
def get_present_gps():
   ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',4800)
   ser.open()
                # open a file to write gps data
   f = open('/home/iiith/Desktop/gps1.txt', 'w')
   data=ser.read(1024) # read 1024 bytes
   f.write(data) #write data into file
   f = open('/home/iiith/Desktop/gps1.txt', 'r')# fetch  the required file
   f1 = open('/home/iiith/Desktop/gps2.txt', 'a+')
   for line in f.read().split('\n'):
       if line.startswith('$GPGGA'):

          try:
              lat, _, lon= line.split(',')[2:5]
              lat=float(lat)
              lon=float(lon)

              print lat/100
              print lon/100
              a=[lat,lon]
              f1.write(lat+",")
              f1.flush()
              f1.write(lon+"\n")
              f1.flush()
              f1.close()
         except:
             pass
while True:
    get_present_gps()
```

Comment: `except: pass` doesn't fix errors; it just makes Python stop telling you about them. If you didn't use that, Python would be giving you some helpful messages about things you're doing wrong.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "can't write to a file"? What is happening when you run your current code? What did you expect to happen instead? If you remove the `try` and `except` blocks, what exceptions do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're covering the error up by using the `except: pass`. Don't do that... ever. At least log the exception.

One error which it definitely covers is `lat+","`, which is going to fail because it's `float+str` and it's not implemented. But there may be more.